# SQL Server Geometry STContains Query Initial Run Takes a Long Time

Tags: sql-server, geometry

We have a case where we have to locate addresses within a certain geographic border. The query runs in less than a second every time EXCEPT the first time the query is run in a given timeframe, usually a day or two. I am thinking it is due to the table getting unloaded from memory. Thus, subsequent queries would run back to the normal second or two time frame. A sample query is below.

```
SELECT * FROM 
[dbo].[TractGeometry] tg inner join tract t on tg.TractId = t.Id 
WHERE [geometry].STContains(geometry::Point(<longitude>, <latitude>, 4326)) = 1
```

My question is, is there a way to ensure these tables stay in memory so the query runs quickly? I have read around the interwebs and have heard of others scheduling a job to run daily to keep them fresh in memory. I am not opposed to doing this, but was wondering if there was a more explicit way of accomplishing this task.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.sqlshack.com/insight-into-the-sql-server-buffer-cache/ and other articles on the Buffer Pool. Something else is making the data get cleared out by querying some other big tables (not very surprising as you are doing a full scan on this table so it needs the whole thing in memory). Consider using some heuristic to narrow down what rows you are comparing (using index seeks only, not full scans), and also increasing RAM and upgrading your disks to SSDs.

Comment: ... and maybe replacing `SELECT *` with only the columns that you need. If the columns used in the select clause, joins and the where clause are all included in a covering index then it won't need to keep the entire table in memory in the first place, only the lesser index.

Comment: What does the query plan look like? Do you have a spatial index on your `[geometry]` column? Unrelated you have lat/long data - why are you using the `geometry` datatype when `geography` exists?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning that is for brevity here.

Comment: @BenThul I did not design this DB so I do not know why that decision was made to go with geometry over geography.